# GUFW from desktop icon

Tags: shortcut-keys, sudo, gufw

I am trying to launch gufw from an icon on my desktop. Now gufw requires sudo to run. I found an application that did the same thing but for nautilus (http://lifehacker.com/5596006/create-an-application-shortcut-to-open-nautilus-as-root-in-ubuntu
and came up with this:

```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Firewall (Root)
   Comment=Set I/0 rules
   Exec=gksudo gufw
   Icon=file-manager
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Application;System;
```

The result is showing in Application-System but nothing happens when I click the icon. If I right-click the select open, then the root login screen appear and all runs smothly.

There is a pair of '()' in the name. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Have you installed `gksu`? you can call that instead of `gksudo`. It generally works much better.

Comment: Changed gksudo for gksu, removed the '()'. No difference

Comment: I don't know what it could be, then. I'll poke around and do some research.

Answer (score 3):

Which Ubuntu version do you use? At least on 14.04 `gufw` already comes with a desktop file, `/usr/share/applications/gufw.desktop`. These are its contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firewall Configuration
Comment=An easy way to configure your firewall
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;Security;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;    X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-SystemSettings;
Exec=gufw
Icon=gufw
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=gufw
X-Unity-Settings-Panel=gufw
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gufw
```

`gufw` doesn't need `gksudo`, it asks for your password on its own. You can also start it from a terminal window and it will ask for the password.

Comment: I too have 14.04 LTS. I went to /usr/share/applications/ and found Firewall Configuration which did the trick. Thanks